# Make a logo in Tikz with name

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, logos

I am trying to make a little logo with latex. I draw the picture (a decision tree) and I'd like to add a text next to it. Moreover, I need the drawing to be small, in size of the text next to it.

Just a random picture to show what kind of shape I'd like to have:

[image]

[source](http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/new_name_logo_and_identity_for_principal_by_lippincott.php#.WIEgFhsrLtQ)

So far I made the drawing where I tried to add some text next to it. No results unfortunately.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \begin{minipage}[c]{7cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    state/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=orange, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    leaf/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=red, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    level distance=0.5cm, growth parent anchor=south
]
\node (State00) [state] {$X$}
   child{ [sibling distance=3cm]
            node (State01) [state] {$f(x)_{1}$}
            child{
                child{ [sibling distance=2cm]
                    node (State02) [state] {$f(x)_{11}$}
                    child{
                        child{
                            node (State03) [leaf] {$\hat{y}_{1}$}
                        }
                    }
                    child{
                        child{ [sibling distance=2.0cm]
                            node (State04) [state] {$\hat{y}_{2}$}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            child{ [sibling distance=2cm]
                child{
                    node (State10) [state] {$f(x)_{12}$}
                    child{
                        child{
                            node (State11) [leaf] {$\hat{y}_{3}$}
                        }
                    }
                    child{
                        child{
                            node (State12) [state] {$\hat{y}_{4}$}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
;    
\end{tikzpicture}]
\end{minipage}%

\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth-7cm}
      Some text describing the image.
      Some text describing the image.
      Some text describing the image.
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output looks as follows:
[image]

And the text should have this form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\setstretch{0.5}

\begin{center}
Nam$\textcolor{orange}{\bm{{\hat{e}}}}$ of New \\
~\\
 Team
\end{center}
```

Could you please point me towards the solution?

**EDIT**

With help of  @Guilherme Zanotelli, I made it work and set the proper proportions. But the logo is very small when I save it into pdf.

How can I make it bigger while keeping the proportion unchanged?

*solved with bigger font*

Comment: I don't get it. What are you trying to accomplish? What does the "Principal" logo has to do with it? Your two chunks of code are (to me) nonsensical... Could you please clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: *shape* you mean *draw and text on the right*?

Comment: Yes, correct. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand what the question actually is, but I suppose one of the issues is to get the `Nam*ê* of New Team` to appear on the right side of the decision tree.

So below is a way to do it within the tikzpicture (no need for minipages).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,pbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}

%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,floats]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
            state/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=orange, circular drop shadow,
                text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
            leaf/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=red, circular drop shadow,
                text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
            level distance=0.5cm, growth parent anchor=south
            ]
            \node (State00) [state] {$X$}
            child{ [sibling distance=3cm]
                node (State01) [state] {$f(x)_{1}$}
                child{
                    child{ [sibling distance=2cm]
                        node (State02) [state] {$f(x)_{11}$}
                        child{
                            child{
                                node (State03) [leaf] {$\hat{y}_{1}$}
                            }
                        }
                        child{
                            child{ [sibling distance=2.0cm]
                                node (State04) [state] {$\hat{y}_{2}$}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                child{ [sibling distance=2cm]
                    child{
                        node (State10) [state] {$f(x)_{12}$}
                        child{
                            child{
                                node (State11) [leaf] {$\hat{y}_{3}$}
                            }
                        }
                        child{
                            child{
                                node (State12) [state] {$\hat{y}_{4}$}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        \node[right] at (current bounding box.east) {\pbox{\textwidth}{\relax\ifvmode\centering\fi Nam$\textcolor{orange}{\bm{{\hat{e}}}}$ of New \\
            ~\\
            Team}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thats exatly it! Only a small question - how could one make the drawing smaller, so it fits more to the text?

Comment: There are conflicting issues in your question. You can scale the whole thing making it smaller using `scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8}` ***but*** you'll lose font size consistency. Another option is to set `every node/.style={font=\small, inner sep=<dim>`  setting `<dim>` accordinly and use a smaller `level distance`, which is essentialy resizing the drawing.

Comment: I think I found the proportions I like, but then the logo is very small when put into pdf. I added a link to the Overleaf so you can see it.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say. You should keep in mind that the dimensions of your drawing are actually real. Which means that the font sizes used are the same when you include your PDF. So you should choose the appropriate font size for "Namê of the Team" and then scale the logo accordingly, not much can be done aside from this...

Comment: Ok, that make sense. Sorry for such a questions, I am really new to Tikz.

Comment: No worries, been there done that. Glad I could be of help and don't be afraid of asking, the worst thing that could happen is not getting answered (which is not very likely here on TeX.SX). :D

Comment: Depends what you ask.

Comment: @cfr (got it right this time) be nice! `;P` Asking about ducks would be a step ahead I guess...

Comment: I had more in mind that some questions might not be ones anybody can answer or, of course, just off-topic. Of course, some answerable questions don't actually get answers, but many do.

Answer (score 4):

This is an adaption of [Guilherme Zanotelli's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349550/), using Forest, of which I am rather font. It also uses `standalone` which is less fuss, in my opinion than `preview` (but uses `preview`, depending on configuration).

In a logo, a key decision will be font choice. While I'm not sure what I would recommend, as that depends a great deal on context and audience, Computer Modern is unlikely to be a good choice. Just as an illustration, I use `kpfonts` in the example below.

I've also made a point of demonstrating how to select an arbitrary font size for the text on the right. The first number is the point size. The second is the baseline skip. Scalable fonts are crucial. By default, you are probably getting bitmap Computer Modern. All well and good in their way, but absolutely unsuitable here. (If you want CM, use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` alone to make sure you get scalable versions.)

I've increased the line widths in the tree because you don't want the lines to disappear if the logo is used at small size. At least, I assume you don't.

[image: logo]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,bm}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  state/.style={fill=orange},
  leaf/.style={fill=red},
  for tree={
    text centered,
    child anchor=parent,
    text=white,
    circle,
    circular drop shadow,
    math content,
    state,
    font=\large,
    edge={line width=1pt},
  },
  for descendants={
    edge path'={(.child anchor) -- +(0,7.5mm) -- (!u.parent anchor)},
    l sep'=15mm,
  },
  l sep'=7.5mm,
  where n children=0{
    !u.s sep'=15mm,
  }{},
  [X
    [f(x)_{1}
      [f(x)_{11}
        [\hat{y}_{1}, leaf]
        [\hat{y}_{2}]
      ]
      [f(x)_{12}
        [\hat{y}_{3}, leaf]
        [\hat{y}_{4}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \node [right, align=center, font=\fontsize{50pt}{75pt}\selectfont] at (current bounding box.east) {Nam$\textcolor{orange}{\bm{{\hat{e}}}}$ of New\\Team};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, what a great answer and recommendations! I will certainly take your comments into account when making final version. Thank you.